# Is there such a thing as a "general semester"?

Tags: undergraduate, terminology

I’m an MSc student and write my thesis about academy retention.

So far the only model I know is that a student enrolls to a certain faculty and begins his studies there.
I’m trying to find models in which the students start their studies in a global semester or year and only after finishing it, choose their desired faculty.
Are there universities or colleges with such a model?

Also, is there a formal name to such a “global semester/year”? I haven’t been able to find anything on the net.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the U.S., it is common to start at a university as an "undeclared major". This gives students an opportunity to take courses in a variety of areas to figure out what interests them. Typically, after a year they must choose a major.

Answer (score 0):

In Germany, there exists something called ***[Studium Generale](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Studium_generale)***¹, which is essentially what you describe.
Its specifics vary between universities, but in most cases you can freely attend introductory courses from all faculties and take exams if you like.

---

<sup>¹ I can only link to the German Wikipedia for this. As of now, the English page does not contain this aspect at all.</sup>

Comment: I wouldn't quite say it is "essentially what you describe". Yes, it can be used that way. However, the *typical* use case for that offer is for people who *do not want to start full-fledged studies* (pensionists/employees with spare time) to get the opportunity of getting to know some in-depth factoids about a variety of subjects. But maybe I'm thinking of something else, as I'm not familiar with exams during a *Studium Generale* (as you cannot earn any degree, it is not clear what exams would be useful for other than a warm feeling and maybe a self-printed diploma for your living room wall).